# useReducer state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem when I apply `useReducer` for reading, updating, deleting data, I cannot set the `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(x, x)` properly. And what I get is undefined.

This is my code:

/context/reducer.js:

```js
import { UPDATE, CREATE, DELETE } from './action'

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log('state en reducer > ', state)
  console.log(action.type, ' > ', action.payload)

  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        employees: state.employees.filter((employee) => {
          return employee.id !== action.payload
        })
      }     
    
    default:
      break;
  }
}

export default reducer
```

/context/action.js:

```js
export const CREATE = 'CREATE_EMPLOYEE'
export const UPDATE = 'UPDATE_EMPLOYEE'
export const DELETE = 'DELETE_EMPLOYEE'
```

/context/AppContext.js:

```
import {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useReducer,
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react'
import reducer from './reducer'
import { UPDATE } from './action'
import axios from 'axios'

export const AppContext = createContext()

export const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([])
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const { data }  = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/employees') /* arrancar json server: json-server --watch db.json --port 8000 */
      setInitialState(data)
      setEmployees(data)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, employees) /* the state is NULL */
//const[state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  console.log('state en context > ', initialState) /* (test) initialState OR state IS 
NULL */

  const updateEmployee = (employee) => dispatch({
    type:UPDATE, payload:employee
  })

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value ={{
        employees, /*THIS WORKS FOR PASS DATA TO THE COMPONENTS*/
        updateEmployee
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAppContext = () => {
  return useContext( AppContext ) 
}
```

my json db (extract):

```json
{ 
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Currey",
      "last_name": "Upson",
      "email": "cupson0@howstuffworks.com",
      "gender": "Male",
      "ip_address": "67.95.8.13"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Jude",
      "last_name": "Marcu",
      "email": "jmarcu1@umich.edu",
      "gender": "Male",
      "ip_address": "176.35.60.28"
    }
  ]
}
```

My components can get the data, for example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { AppContext, useAppContext } from '../context/AppContext'
import Edit from './Edit'

const Show = () => {
  const { employees } = useAppContext(AppContext)
  // console.log('employees en show > ', employees)
/*here mapping the data and is fine*/
}
```

Comment: Your reducer `default` case is missing returning a state value. Also from what I can tell your `useReducer` hook and state will only be initialized to the the empty array that is the initial `employees` state value. Other than it's not clear what any issue might be. Can you [edit] to clarify specifically what the issue or problem is and include a complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the reducer is only ever used the very *first* time the useReducer line is encountered. At that point, your fetch hasn't even started, much less returned.

Add an initialize type action that takes the payload of employees, and then dispatch that in the success from your fetch.

Also your default in the switch should return the state.